# Obtain the user name in google analytics api

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

After obtaining an access token, I can get an Analytics object

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
       .setTransport(httpTransport)
       .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
       .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientId)
       .build()
       .setAccessToken(accessToken);

    Analytics analytics=new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
       .setApplicationName(applicationName).build();
```

Is possible, at this point , get the user with which I got the token?

Comment: You should not be sending personal(user) information to Google Analytics.

Comment: I don't think he is sending data to Google Analytics I think he is trying to retrieve data from the Google analytics api, that's what the question implies anyway I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [Accounts: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list) you can get the email address of the user that authenticated your access to the Google Analytics api I think that's the best you can do.

you could try and add the profile or email scope should give you a bit more info about the user that was authenticated but then you have to go though the Google+ api to get the databack.